# JQuery Select2 dropdown options exceed container width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I have a select2 that is in a bootstrap column. When the select is opened and the options are showing, the option list is wider than the bootstrap column the select is contained in. This is because the select options are rendered as a div at the bottom of .

Is there a way to force the options list to respect the width of the bootstrap column (original input parent)? I don't want to use Js if possible, since this is a wide issue and it would be impossible to manually set the width with Js everywhere it's happening.

I am setting `width: 100%` on the select, but that doesn't affect the options list.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29x8veh0/

Comment: The fiddle is not good, it lakes the select 2, I just see a normal select....

Comment: @BENARDPatrick that's what a select2 looks like

Comment: Seriously ? Why do I have this error in your fiddle ? `$(...).select2 is not a function`

Comment: @BENARDPatrick make sure Javascript + JQuery is selected in the top of the javascript pane

Comment: Yep, I see this, but there is no entry about the cdn for select2....

Comment: Look at this one, it's better https://jsfiddle.net/aus195by/,  look at the resource pan on the left, you ccan include each library you need in inserting its CDN links